# Powerpoint chart to excel relative link

Tags: excel, charts, powerpoint

My client asked me to generate a powerpoint report with many charts linked to an excel data file.

My problem is that though the presentation slides are static their data is dynamic.

I want to link the charts data to the excel file (where i can place my macro), but the problem is that on the client's pc, things will get mixed up since the excel file is linked to a specific path on my PC.

Is there a way to use relative path?

Comment: How are you linking your charts to xl (data sheet, as olebject etc?) and what ppt version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OLE links (like links to XLS data) cannot be relative.

In past versions of Office, if the linked source XLS wasn't found on the path the link pointed to, PPT would look for the file in the same directory as the PPT itself and if found there, would use it.  MS seems to have "improved" that feature.  It no longer works, near as I can tell.

You could conceivably put your files in a specific directory and create that same directory on the target PC, though.

Or if you can run code on the client end, supply a macro that looks for the files in the same directory as the PPT and resets the links to point to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Does the client need to see the data behind the charts?  If not, then you can break the links on the charts and send them an unlinked version (basically just pics of the charts)
If they need to see the data behind the charts or make changes to the chart format, you may need to use embedded charts or excel objects and paste links in the data sheet.
I am currently using the second method, but finding the links are not that stable (opening a chart without the source file open tends to make the data change and breaking the links with VBA is not a piece of cake.